# Regex for validate password in ReactJS

Tags: regex, validation, reactjs

Can we do `regex` pattern checking for **password validation** in `reactJS`?

Since I am new to `reactJS`, I need `regex` pattern for validating the **password**.

Following are the **conditions** for `validating password`.

a) Password should contains one **Capital** letter

b) It should start with **special character** `@` or `#`

c) It should not contain any **vowel** `a,e,i,o,u` letters

d) It should be **alphanumeric**.

e) **Length** of password should be between `range 8 to 14`

Comment: I have no idea to try the above, since I have shortage in time for delivering other due to personal work.

Comment: agreed with @aryamccarthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check all rules in one pass - try this formula:

```
^([@#](?=[^aeiou]{7,13}$)(?=[[:alnum:]]{7,13}$)(?=.*[A-Z]{1,}.*$).+)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dx2kPQ/1)

Answer (score 4):

The simpliest way is to check all rules separately.

There's a function i wrote for you:

```
function password_validate(password) {
    var re = {
        'capital' : /[A-Z]/,
        'digit'   : /[0-9]/,
        'except'  : /[aeiou]/,
        'full'    : /^[@#][A-Za-z0-9]{7,13}$/
    };
    return re.capital .test(password) && 
           re.digit   .test(password) && 
          !re.except  .test(password) && 
           re.full    .test(password);
}
```

Or the same function in one line:

```
function password_validate(p) {
    return /[A-Z]/.test(p) && /[0-9]/.test(p) && !/[aeiou]/.test(p) && /^[@#][A-Za-z0-9]{7,13}$/.test(p);
}
```

Comment: Do no provide answers to users that doesn't show effort to solve the problem, ***SO isn't a code-writing website***.

Comment: @PedroLobito, is it your personal position or there is some regulation rules on a site?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266270/specific-warnings-to-newbies-about-homework-code-writing-please-debug-and-sscce

Comment: @PedroLobito, ok, this is personal position of group of people, includes you... it's not official position... so, do not impose it on me, please...

Answer (score 2):

This regex will work :

`^[@#](?=.{7,13}$)(?=\w{7,13})(?=[^aeiou_]{7,13})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)`

**Explanation**

`^[@#]` Starts with `@` or `#`

> Now we can add some conditions this way :
>
> `(?=condition)(?=condition)(?=condition)`
>
> This means "match condition but after that continue matching at the original match-point."
>
> You can add as many conditions as you want, and this will be an "and."

`(?=.{7,13}$)` Length of password should be between range 8 to 14

`(?=\w{7,13})` It should be alphanumeric.

`(?=[^aeiou_]{7,13})` It should not contain any vowel a,e,i,o,u letters or underscore which is matched by `\w`

`(?=.*[A-Z])` Password should contains a Capital letter

`(?=.*\d)` It should be alphanumeric so it should contain a digit

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pv73KC/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
password_validate = (password) => {
    var re = {
        capital: /(?=.*[A-Z])/,
        length: /(?=.{7,40}$)/,
        specialChar: /[ -\/:-@\[-\`{-~]/,
        digit: /(?=.*[0-9])/,
    };
    return (
        re.capital.test(password) &&
        re.length.test(password) &&
        re.specialChar.test(password) &&
        re.digit.test(password)
    );
};
```

1. /(?=.*[A-Z])/ **- will check at least one capital char**
2. /(?=.{7,40}$)/ **- will check the char length between 7 to 40**
3. /[ -/:-@[-`{-~]/ **- will check at least one symbol**
4. /(?=.*[0-9])/ **- will check at least one number**

Comment: Please add some explanation rather than posting only code.

Answer (score 0):

Standard one - `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/.test(paswrd)`